# Value On UITextField Changes On Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

Before asking this question I have googled a lot and not able to find a suitable answer.

I have a tableView with `Three` sections and `n` number of columns. The no. of rows in each section is also not fixed. The last two columns contains a `UITextField` and initially the value in each textfield is `0.00`. So after entering the Value in each row if I close that section the textField value is revert back to `0.00`. Can anybody tell me how to save this textField value.

Here is my code.

I'm using a custom Cell `GenericTableViewCell` and `self.columnHeaderArray` determines how many columns in tableview. columnHeaderArray Value contains the colum details like the column type, value etc...

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
GenericTableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[GenericTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"withColumns:self.columnHeaderArray];

        for (GenericTableColumn *theColumn in self.columnHeaderArray)
        {
            [self processDataForCell:cell forColumn:theColumn atIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
     return cell;
    }
}
```

`processDataForCell` is a method where I updated the column with values and textfield. In this method I check the column type and insert values into each column.

The code for that is.

```
switch (column.columnType)
    {
        case textField:
        {
          UITextField *lblTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, label.frame.size.width - 10, label.frame.size.height - 6)];

          lblTextField.delegate = self;

          lblTextField.text = theValue; // setting the textField value iniatally 0.00

          lblTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
          lblTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
          lblTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

          [label addSubview:lblTextField];

          break;
       }
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I solved the issue thanks to @Ayazmon and @naturalnOva for their comments and leading me to solve this.

**The Code:**

In my `.h` file I declared a `NSMutableDictionary` named `textFieldValues` like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary <NSString *, NSString *> *textFieldValues;
```

And in `viewDidLoad` I instantiate this Dictionary as

```
self.textFieldValues = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

In `processDataForCell` method I replaced my code with

```
switch (column.columnType)
{
    case textField:
    {
      UITextField *lblTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, label.frame.size.width - 10, label.frame.size.height - 6)];

        lblTextField.delegate = self;

        lblTextField.tag = indexPath.row;

        if ([self.textFieldValues count] != 0) {

            // pass in the indexPath from cellForRow
            NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld-%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
            lblTextField.text = self.textFieldValues[key];

        } else {

            lblTextField.text = theValue; // For setting the textField value iniatally 0.00
        }

        lblTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        lblTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        lblTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

        [label addSubview:lblTextField];

        break;
     }
 }
```

And for me `UITextField delegate` method `textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)` is not being called. So I used `textFieldShouldReturn` method.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld-%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
   self.textFieldValues[key] = textField.text;

  return self.textFieldValues[key];

}
```

**Thanku Guys**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you scroll your cell's off view they are deallocated. Each time the cell scrolls back into view it's re-initialized. If you want to retain the value of the textfield I'd save it's contents when you can and hold onto that value.

I have done this before by holding on to a dictionary of Strings that contain the values for my indexPaths. Each time the textfield resigns as first responder I then store the value of the field in my dictionary.

You should register the `UITextField`'s delegate in your view controller and override `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)` where you can access the value of the textfield.

**Example:**

Create a property for the field values:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *textFieldValues;
```

Override the `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld-%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
    self.textFieldValues[key] = textField.text;
}
```

Using your above code, assign a tag to the textfield and assign the fields contents using the dictionary:

```
UITextField *lblTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, label.frame.size.width - 10, label.frame.size.height - 6)];
lblTextField.delegate = self;
lblTextField.tag = indexPath.row;

// pass in the indexPath from cellForRow
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld-%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
lblTextField.text = self.textFieldValues[key];

lblTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
lblTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
lblTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

[label addSubview:lblTextField];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: sure, here is an example.

Comment: k let me try this and let u know :)

Comment: i'm getting error in declaration of nsdictionary saying `Too few type arguments for class 'NSMutableDictionary (have 1, expected 2) `

Comment: You'll need to instantiate the dictionary. Put `self.textFieldValues = [NSMutableDictionary new];` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: no this is not because of instantiating.. error is showing in `.h` file

Comment: when i changed `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary<NSString *> *textFieldValues;` to `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary <NSString *, NSString *> *textFieldValues;` the error gone.. is it correct

Comment: its working i'm able to update the value but the thing is its updating all the section not depending on particular row

Comment: If you are working with sections you can use a key with the section and row like so: `NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld-%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];`. Make sure to update the key in when create your cell & assigning a new value in `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)`. My answer is updated with this change as well.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called whenever you try to display a cell in `UITableView` and in your code you create a completely new cell for the given `indexPath` every time. So when you set the value to the `lblTextField` and then displaying it again it gets resetted. My advice is restore the value then in `processDataForCell` method set the restored value to `lblTextField` that way the value will have consistency.

Comment: yeah i know that but my table view has unknown sections and each section has unknown no of rows. so how can i store the value

Comment: Add your class as the delegate (`UITextFieldDelegate`) to your textfield by  `textField.delegate = self` and in `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate function retrieve the value by `textField.text` then you can store it in a class variable or if you want to keep it locally you can use `Core Data` or `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Ok lets say you saved it with `NSUserDefaults` the code would be: Saving - `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"MyTextFieldValue"]` and Retrieving - `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"MyTextFieldValue"]` .

Comment: see, if i save like this then how could i pass this value according to which section, row and column... i have n no of sections.. and in each section i have n no of rows. so how can i know which value to assign to which textfield while retrieving

Comment: Well you can also save a dictionary type of object with this method. So you can create a key based on section and row then save the value to that key. Also saving the value and using it when it's needed is another issue, first try to save a single value to see if it solves your problem then work on saving multiple values and test again :)